# How can I add a UIProgressView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c

I want to add UIProgressView in cell. I want to make it progress with the time.

Comment: Can you please clarify and use proper punctuation and capitalization?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an activity indicator which is very similar to the UIProgressView.

Comment: What ever happened to this being a place where proper punctuation was used?